# can change facebook app invitation text using graph api

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can we change facebook app invitation text using facebook Graph api ?

Generally this has format - "Inviter name sent you a request", can we replace this text to our own ?

(This get displayed as a notification on fb wall.)

I am using below code -

```
- (void)load:(BOOL)NeedToSendAppRequest AndMessage:(NSString*)message AndFriendID:(NSString*)friendID {

    NSString *urlString = nil;
    isNeedToSendAppRequest = NeedToSendAppRequest;

    if (NeedToSendAppRequest) {
        NSString *redirectUrlString = FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL;
        NSString *authFormatString = @"https://m.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=%@&target_url=fb%@&to=%@&message=%@&redirect_uri=%@";
        urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:authFormatString, _apiKey, _apiKey,friendID,message,redirectUrlString];  
    }else{
        NSString *redirectUrlString = @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        NSString *authFormatString = @"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&type=user_agent&display=touch";
        urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:authFormatString, _apiKey, redirectUrlString, _requestedPermissions];
    }

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [_webView loadRequest:request];   

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the sample below - `friendToInviteCSVString` is a comma separated string of friend FB IDs that you want to invite.  You can set a custom invite message in the `message` key of the parameter dictionary.

This is using the 3.x FB iOS SDK, by the way:

```
 //Remove last comma from CSV string
 friendToInviteCSVString = [friendToInviteCSVString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];

 NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           NSLocalizedString(@"Check out this awesome app.", @"Check out this awesome app."), @"message",
                                           friendToInviteCSVString, @"to", nil];



//Do FB invites
DDLogVerbose(@"Active fb session: %@", [FBSession activeSession]);

[FBWebDialogs presentDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession] dialog:@"apprequests" parameters:parameters handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
 {
      DDLogVerbose(@"Facebook closed dialog with result: %d, URL: %@, error: %@", result, resultURL, error);
 }];
```

EDIT:

Ok so I went digging around in my legacy code and here's a sample using FBDialog which is what's available in the SDK version you're using.  First you need a `Facebook` object:

```
Facebook *facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kFBAppID andDelegate:self];

 //Check if token is valid
if (FBSession.activeSession.accessToken)
{
    DLog(@"Init FB with activeSession, token: %@ and expirationDate: %@", FBSession.activeSession.accessToken, FBSession.activeSession.expirationDate);

    self.facebook.accessToken = FBSession.activeSession.accessToken;
    self.facebook.expirationDate = FBSession.activeSession.expirationDate;
}
else
{
    //No FB Token, do something here - ask user for permission, etc
}

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   NSLocalizedString(@"Check out this awesome app.", @"Facebook apprequest invite message"), @"message", friendsToInvite, @"to", nil];

 [self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:parameters andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for help jai govindani.. :) but any idea about Graph api for same would be more helpful, since my app is almost completed and i can't change fb sdk this time.

Comment: So you're using a pre-3.x version of the SDK?

Comment: I used the class from this link :- https://github.com/megastep/facebook-iphone-sdk/blob/master/src/FBDialog.m

Comment: Can you post the code you're currently using to send apprequests so I can modify it, instead of me posting something that you might not be able to use because of your SDK version?

Comment: See latest edit, using FBDialog. Note however that FBDialog isn't called directly but is used through the `Facebook` object as per FB's instructions in `FBDialog.h`